# Unable to find an app in the App Store

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

I am trying to locate an app in the App Store, but I couldn't find it. I want to download it to my iPad. All the software on iPad is updated to the latest available version.

The App name has been entered correctly. Is it possible that the app is blocked for certain areas/regions?

How can I locate and download it?

Comment: Is it an iOS or a macOS app?

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Which Apps are you trying to download? Where do you live? But yes, some apps are blocked to some regions... For Example: The 'HBO Now' app is not available on Brasil's App Store because HBO Now is not licensed to operate here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you specify the name of the app. Did you try searching for it on Google?

Answer (score 4):

You can try visiting the developer's website and click the App Store link for the app. Searching for the app on the Web can also fetch you the App Store link.

If you have previously downloaded the app and are not able to find it anymore on the App Store, there's a possibility that either the developer of Apple has taken the app off the App Store or the same is no longer available in your region.

The best way to resolve is to get in touch with the developer via their website.

Comment: Works OK, I changed the Region . Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a web search with `Name of your app + iTunes`.By this way you can easily find the App Store link for the app, which can take you to directly to the app in the App Store.

For example, if you search `Reeder 3 iTunes`, then you can find [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reeder-3/id880001334?mt=12) App Store link.

Comment: Hi Changlele, I have located the App as you suggested, but I get the message: "Loading" for many minutes and does not load anything. Maybe it is blocked ?

Comment: @dave Can you share the link or screenshot for what you located. Please edit it into the question.